# SignaIr Understanding that the connection has ended on the server side

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

What is the equivalent of this socket io code in signaIr?

```
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    count--;
    io.emit('disUser', count);
    console.log('user disconnected');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that SignalR uses the idea of 'hubs' which makes the translation from socket.io a little muddy.  Here is the SignalR code:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        count--;
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("disUser", count);
        Console.WriteLine("user disconnected");
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

Documentation for handling connection events can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1#handle-events-for-a-connection